# Add additional associative array in 2x2 multidimensional array but perserve key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Howdie do,

I have one multidimensional associative array of server types. This array contains a sub array of values.

It's easier to see:

```
$servers = array('Dell R410 Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz' => array('Model' =>$R410Model, 'Description' =>$R410Desc,'Counter' => $R410HexCoreE5650Count));
```

I want to add additional server type associative array. This is what I've done:

```
$servers[] = array('Atoms D510 1.66Ghz' => array('Model' =>$AtomModel, 'Description' =>$AtomDesc,'Counter' => $AtomCount));

$servers[] = array('Celerons 2.40Ghz' => array('Model' =>$CeleronModel, 'Description' =>$CeleronDesc,'Counter' => $CELERONCount));
```

It does add the value, but it does it by index and not the actual server type key.

```
Array ( [Dell R410 Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz] => Array ( [Model] => DELL R410 [Description] => Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz [Counter] => 25 ) 

[0] => Array ( [Atoms D510 1.66Ghz] => Array ( [Model] => ATOM [Description] => D510 1.66Ghz [Counter] => 1 ) ) 

[1] => Array ( [Celerons 2.40Ghz] => Array ( [Model] => [Description] => [Counter] => 0 ) ) )
```

How do I move the sub arrays up one so that it adds them by key and not index. So that it looks like this

```
 Array ( [Dell R410 Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz] => Array ( [Model] => DELL R410 [Description] => Dual Xeon X5650 Hexacore 2.66 GHz [Counter] => 25 ) 

 Array ( [Atoms D510 1.66Ghz] => Array ( [Model] => ATOM [Description] => D510 1.66Ghz [Counter] => 1 ) ) 

 Array ( [Celerons 2.40Ghz] => Array ( [Model] => [Description] => [Counter] => 0 ) ) )
```

Comment: `$servers[SERVER_NAME] = array(WITH THE DATA IN IT)` :)

Comment: just point it out to which server you want, just like that comment above ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just put it in an answer for you, because it is a simple typo.

Instead of creating an array object with an integer index (`$server[] = array(....`), what you want to do is this:

```
$servers['Atoms D510 1.66Ghz'] = array('Model' =>$AtomModel, 'Description' =>$AtomDesc,'Counter' => $AtomCount);
$servers['Celerons 2.40Ghz'] = array('Model' =>$CeleronModel, 'Description' =>$CeleronDesc,'Counter' => $CELERONCount);
```